# Issue when loading an XNA project at home computer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xna, project, file-not-found

I have just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Pro and at school we run the same version but at home I get errors.

> F:\xna\LearningXNA4.0\Chapter 02\Collision\Collision\Collision\Collision.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'Collision.csproj'.
>
> F:\xna\LearningXNA4.0\Chapter 02\Collision\Collision\Collision\Collision.csproj(131,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>
> F:\xna\LearningXNA4.0\Chapter 02\Collision\Collision\CollisionContent\CollisionContent.contentproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'CollisionContent.contentproj'.
>
> F:\xna\LearningXNA4.0\Chapter 02\Collision\Collision\CollisionContent\CollisionContent.contentproj(26,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.ContentPipeline.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.**

Please note that I have installed XNA and Visual Studio to drive `E:` for `C:` is full and `E:` is empty.

The error message is telling me to edit the settings some how to update the change but i cant find out where. I'm hoping someone here will know.

Answer (score 0):

Every project file, such as `Collision.csproj` is basically a text file. Simply open them in notepad (or in VS if you'd like to see nice markup) and edit the paths that lead to wrong places.